# Matlab numerical integration

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate x using matlab, and that task is simple by using the following commands:

```
syms x

a=int(x)
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to implement numerical integration. I want to integrate x using a set amount of intervals using different techniques.

Can anyone help me with the syntax call for numerical integration? The MathWorks site isn't very helpful.

I also do know there is a method called traps, but I'm looking for other methods within matlab, like Riemann sum approximation.

**Update**

So specifically what I'm looking for is a function that will break x into 8 pieces of area and then add those 8 pieces together. Is there a predefined function other than trapz that does such a thing?

Okay, I think I've come to the conclusion that there is no such thing. You have to make your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numerical integration you have a broad number of functions at your disposal:

```
trapz
quad
quadgk
integral
```

for uni-dimensional integration.

If, instead, you are interested in multi-dimensional integration techniques, you may think of making use of the following functions

```
dblquad
quad2d
integral2
integral3
```

**EDIT**

In your case, I would proceed this way:

```
x = 0:.1:2;
y = x;
trapz(x,y);
```

or

```
y = @(x) x;
quad(y,0,2);
```

**EDIT 2**

Give this a look:

```
clc,clear

s = 0:7;
y = @(x) x;

k = 1;
for ii = 1:numel(s)-1
  f(k) = quad(y,s(k), s(k+1));
  k = k + 1;
end
sum(f)
```

Comment: So to make sure I'm understanding this right, the reason those functions wouldn't work for me previously was because I was using, "syms x" instead of making x a vector of increment length "b" with start at "a" and end at "b." From there, I can call any of the functions you mentioned? Wow! thanks

Comment: @Mechy: `syms` is calling the **symbolic toolbox**, whereas the functions I have named above calculate your integral numerically.

Comment: can you explain your notation on "y=@(x) x" a little more. What is that doing? Can I specify my interval length or amount of intervals with quad? "y=f(x)" doesn't work either. Matlab doesn't like that. Or are you saying that I compute the values of the function at those locations and then input those into a vector?

Comment: I redirect you to: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html. It`s gonna help you with understanding the **function handle**.

Comment: So to make sure I'm understanding this right, "y=@(x)x" takes the array x as an input and then performs an operation on it after the first close parenthesis. for example, y=@(x)x^2 would take the array x and then square each number in it and pass it to y.

Comment: Are there any matlab functions that allow you to specify the number of intervals, or is trapz the only one?

Comment: the other functions are already taking care of that for you, so you don't need to specify any interval since it's done internally. But if you edit your question with a study-case, perhaps I can be more helpful.

Comment: but is there a way where I can specify the interval amount of intervals?

Comment: So if I'm looking at that correctly, I think what you're doing is doing a whole bunch of mini-integrations using the quad function and then adding them all together. Thanks for all the help. I just ended up making my own integration function with all the stuff I learned.