# Calculate integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am given the following data:

[image: Data]

and I am asked to calculate the integral of Cp/T dT from 113.7 to 264.4.

I am unsure of how I should solve this. If I want to use the integral command, I need a function, but I don't know how my function should be in that case.

I have tried:

```
function func = Cp./T
T = [...]
Cp=[...]
end
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ***cumtrapz*** function in MATLAB.

```
T = [...]
Cp=[...]
CpdivT = Cp./T
I = cumtrapz(T, CpdivT)
```

You can read more about the function at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html

Comment: Another approach I can think of is to fit your data to a function (say polynomial or linear or exponential depending on the trend of the data). This can be done using `fit` command. Then integrate that function using the integral command.

Comment: But for the cumtrapz code, how do I specify that I want T to go from 113.7 to 264.4?

Comment: You can interpolate between the points of interest and use cumtrapz. I have provided a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach using `interp1` and `integral` using plain vanilla settings.
Would only use more sophisticated numerical techniques if required for application. You can examine the `'RelTol'` and `'AbsTol'` options in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) for `integral`.

**Numerical Integration:** (w/ linear interpolation)

```
% MATLAB R2017a
T = [15 20 30 40 50 70 90 110 130 140 160 180 200 220 240 260 270 275 285 298]';
Cp = [5.32 10.54 21.05 30.75 37.15 49.04 59.91 70.04 101.59 103.05 106.78 ...
    110.88 114.35 118.70 124.31 129.70 88.56 90.07 93.05 96.82]';

fh =@(t) interp1(T,Cp./T,t,'linear');

t1 = 113.7;
t2 = 264.4;
integral(fh,t1,t2)
```

> ans = 91.9954

**Alternate Methods of Interpolation:**
Your results will depend on your method of interpolation (see code & graphic below).

```
% Results depend on method of interpolation
Linear = integral(@(t) interp1(T,Cp./T,tTgts,'linear'),t1,t2)   % = 91.9954
Spline = integral(@(t) interp1(T,Cp./T,tTgts,'spline'),t1,t2)   % = 92.5332
Cubic  = integral(@(t) interp1(T,Cp./T,tTgts,'pchip'),t1,t2)    % = 92.0383
```

[image: Graphic show impact of interpolation method choice]

Code for graphic:

```
tTgts = T(1):.01:T(end);

figure, hold on, box on
p(1) = plot(tTgts,interp1(T,Cp./T,tTgts,'linear'),'b-','DisplayName','Linear')
p(2) = plot(tTgts,interp1(T,Cp./T,tTgts,'spline'),'r-','DisplayName','Spline')
p(3) = plot(tTgts,interp1(T,Cp./T,tTgts,'pchip'),'g-','DisplayName','Cubic')
p(4) = plot(T,Cp./T,'ks','DisplayName','Data')
xlim([floor(t1) ceil(t2)])
legend('show')

% Cosmetics
xlabel('T')
ylabel('Cp/T')
for k = 1:4, p(k).LineWidth = 2; end
```

---

**A poor approximation:** (to get rough order of magnitude estimate)

```
tspace = T(2:end)-T(1:end-1);
midpt = mean([Cp(1:end-1) Cp(2:end)],2);
sum(midpt.*tspace)./sum(tspace)
```

And you can see we're in the ballpark (makes me feel more comfortable at least).

---

**Other viable MATLAB Functions:**  `quadgk` | `quad`

```
% interpolation  method affects answer if using `interp1()`
quadgk(@(t) interp1(T,Cp./T,t,'linear'),t1,t2)    
quad(@(t) interp1(T,Cp./T,t,'linear'),t1,t2)
```

**Functions that would require more work:** `trapz` | `cumtrapz`
Notice that `trapz` and `cumtrapz` both require unit spacing; to use these would require first interpolating with unit spacing.

---

**Related Posts:** (found after answer already completed)
[Matlab numerical integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16656953/8239061)
[How to numerically integrate vector data in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50713796/8239061)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better for your problem. Take note that I have assumed 2nd order polynomial fits your data well. You may want to get a better model structure if the fit is unsatisfactory.

```
% Data
T = [15 20 30 40 50 70 90 110 130 140 160 180 200 220 240 260 270 275 285 298];
Cp = [5.32 10.54 21.05 30.75 37.15 49.04 59.91 70.04 101.59 103.05 106.78 110.88 114.35 118.70 124.31 129.70 88.56 90.07 93.05 96.82];

% Fit function using 2nd order polynomial
f = fit(T',Cp'./T','poly2');

% Compare fit to actual data
plot(f,T,Cp./T)

% Create symbolic function
syms x
func = f.p1*x*x + f.p2*x + f.p3;

% Integrate function 
I = int(func,113.7,264.4);

% Convert solution from symbolic to numeric value
V = double(I);
```

The result is `92.7839`

Comment: Is there any concern over the output from `plot(fit(T,Cp./T,'poly2'),T,Cp./T)` ?

Comment: The only concern I may have is the rsquared value of the fit (about 0.76). This is however good for the task at hand. Do you have other concerns?

Comment: I don't know the underlying relationship between these variables so if there's some sort of physics involved, that might affect this, *but*, `plot(fit(T,Cp./T,'poly2'),T,Cp./T)` makes me concerned about this approximation (though numerically it gets close by luck). I'm also not an expert here so always looking to learn.

Comment: I have your concern too. If the underlying physics is known, you can use the data to estimate the parameters. However, the use of polynomial has some advantages such as focusing on the trend rather than the data points. In a case where the data is corrupted with noise or several outliers are present, it will give a better result than interpolation (linear etc) which just focuses on two or three points at a time. Linear will probably be the worst if the data is noisy or outliers are present. For experimental data (within good range of data points), you can't go wrong with 2nd order polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for your note.  I completely agree, especially over the concern regarding overfitting to noise.